# VS2010 only runs one TestMethod

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I am admittedly new to unit testing in VS2010, but I'm having a problem that I can't seem to resolve.

No matter how many classes I have in Test project decorated with `[TestClass]` or how many methods within those test classes are decorated with `[TestMethod]`.  Whenever I run all tests in the solution.  only one test gets run.  and it passes.  all the others are ignored.

Is there some master list I'm suppose to update? If so where is it!?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. In the toolbar at the top of your vs window click the Test menu item
2. Select "Create New Test List" Give the list a name and click ok.
3. In the "Test List Editor" tab, select the "All Loaded Tests" check box in the left column
4. in the right column, right click and select "Run Checked Tests"

That should do it.

Good Luck,

Patrick

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I think I'm almost there however, when I select "All Loaded Tests" only the single test shows up.  How do I add test methods to this list?

Comment: Strange... Can you show me the full code for a single test method that isn't showing up?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a test method with one or more parameters, it will not get run.
try to use test methods with no parameters.